# Computing Ext-groups from resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In a practice exercise on homological algebra, I have been given a ring $R=\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^4)$, together with two $R$-modules $M_1=R/(X)$ and $M_2=R/(X^2)$. Now the question I am trying to answer is to compute $\text{Ext}^1(M_i,M_j)$ for $i=1,2$, and to give non-zero

$$f\in\text{Ext}^1(M_1,M_2),g\in\text{Ext}^1(M_2,M_2)\quad\text{and}\quad h\in \text{Ext}^1(M_2,M_1)$$

such that the higher product $\mu_3(f,g,h)\in \text{Ext}^1(M_1,M_1)$ is non-zero., where $\mu_3$ is a higher product on the $A_\infty$-algebra $\text{Ext}^\bullet(M_1,M_1)$. What I did was that I started with the following free resolution $P_1^\bullet$

$$\cdots \xrightarrow{\cdot \text{X}}R\xrightarrow{\cdot \text{X}^3}R\xrightarrow{\cdot \text{X}}R\xrightarrow{\cdot\pi_ \text{0}}M_1$$

of $M_1$ and a free resolution $P_2^\bullet$ of $M_2$

$$\cdots \xrightarrow{\cdot \text{X}^2}R\xrightarrow{\cdot \text{X}^2}R\xrightarrow{\cdot \text{X}^2}R\xrightarrow{\cdot\pi_ \text{1}}M_2$$

Those resolutions should suffice to calculate the Ext-groups, which are now defined by $\text{Ext}^1(M_i,M_j)=H^1\left(\text{Hom}(P^\bullet_i,P^\bullet_j)\right)$. The problem is that I get different answers using different methods, so I would like to see in this example how one can compute the $\text{Ext}^1$'s, so that I can try it myself in a different example.

Also, I am a little bit puzzled by this $\mu_3$. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I would think what you actually want to compute is $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M_i, M_j) = H^1(\operatorname{Hom}(P_i^\cdot, M_j))$.

Comment: You can compute $\operatorname{Ext}$ using a double/total complex too, but you'll need an injective resolution of the covariant variable instead (but I don't see the point in resolving both variables).

Comment: Can you explain how you get different answers using different methods?